# Is it possible to separate the application of statements inside database transactions?

Tags: transaction, sqlite

This is a simple scenario that I encountered recently.

I will fabricate a minimal scenario to illustrate the problem.

We have a database table with a column of IDs used as a foreign key to something (but which is not specified as a foreign key; it's being used to hold an ephemeral mapping index temporarily, in a really rather dangerous way that relies on external state). Each row has a value populated here. This column of data subsequently must be updated with a new mapping.

An example of a valid mapping:

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 4
2 -> 0
```

An example dataset:

```
2
1
0
2
```

Obvious desired result:

```
0
4
1
0
```

Implementation (pseudocode):

```
for (mapping in map) {
    sql("update table set value = " + mapping.to + " where value = " + mapping.from + ";")
}
```

Pretty straightforward but almost as obvious is that this is completely wrong because the result we see is

```
0
4
4
0
```

The third row got the mapping applied twice.

I was thinking that maybe if the N (where N is the number of mappings) statements are executed in a transaction that it may solve the problem. But I'm not so sure, and I don't really see why it would. The transaction would just guarantee that either row 3 got zero or both mappings applied, but what I need is for only the one mapping. It basically seems like I need a whole new column to even accomplish such a simple operation in a straightforward way.

How is this sort of situation dealt with usually? I feel like I'm missing something trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like

```
UPDATE tab1 set value = 
   CASE value
     WHEN 0 THEN 1 
     WHEN 1 THEN 4
     WHEN 2 THEN 0 
   END;
```

If you need to treat values which are not listed in `CASE` in a different way, say don't change it ,  you need to add `ELSE` to `CASE` as  **ypercubeᵀᴹ** pointed out:

```
UPDATE tab1 set value = 
       CASE value
         WHEN 0 THEN 1 
         WHEN 1 THEN 4
         WHEN 2 THEN 0 
         ELSE value
       END;
```

Or you can create a new table, insert  all mappings there,
and then (assuming mapping is unique)

```
UPDATE  tab1 t SET value = 
 (SELECT new_val from mapping_table t2 WHERE t2.old_val = t.value)
```

Comment: Today I (re-)learned about `CASE`. thanks.

Comment: Practically speaking, I think that a good compromise to do here (which in my particular situation was entirely valid, it's going outside of the bounds of the original question) would have been to use a new database column and that way we can be much clearer about what data inside the database actually means, which is a nice property

Comment: It would be better if the `CASE` had an `ELSE value`. In case the column has some values that are not included in the mapping, not to be changed to NULL.